# How to save 3D object’s real world position in ARKit and user can see it in any next session?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, world-map

When I place 3D object on detected plane by hitting on plane, I want to save that object’s real world coordinates and see that object in next session at that coordinates only.

With ARWorldMap it’s depending on feature points and detected plane.  If I place object on Notebook (detected plane) which is located on table and on that notebook I place 3D object and I am using ARWorldMap and loading object at that saved position then it’s get loaded but If I place that notebook on another point of table and try to load that object then also it will get placed because detected plane is notebook.

But I want that instead of that detected plane(Notebook) I want to place my object in that position only where I placed my object before. How can I achieve it? I need to use latitude and longitude of that hitted point or I can get it by real world position?

Comment: May I know what is wrong in this question?

Comment: Not sure why anyone downvoted the question without providing a comment. This is a legitimate need that ARKit (currently version 3) doesn't provide a solution for.

Answer (score 1):

Real-world position in ARKit is based on the world origin, which is different every time you start your app from a different physical location. What you need is to use Core Location and save off the anchor's lat/long yourself.